# Python String Manipulation

Tags: python

Having a hard time understanding what is happening in this snippet of code. Particularly with the 2nd line of code.

```
for line in infile:
    data = line.strip('\n').split(':')
    user_dict[data[0]] = data[1]
```

Comment: You mean the `data = ` line? Which part of the line you don't understand?

Comment: probably you mean the third line, because second line is quite straightforward. if you have trouble to understand second line, u could get help from https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html, strip() means removing the leading and trailing character, in your case it means remove leading and trailing '\n'. For third line, data[0] and data[1] are both string, so it meas a dictionary named as user_dict, and its index is data[0] and its value is data[1].

Answer (score 1):

The line sets the variable `data` equal to the string represented by the variable `line` with the new line character `'\n'` removed and then split anywhere a `:` occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It parses a file having this structure:

```
a:52
b:hi
key:value
```

`for line in infile:` is a loop for each line in the file. Each line (except for the last maybe) ends with new-line symbol `\n`.

`line.strip('\n')` removes the new-line symbol.

`.split(':')` splits the string into strings there were separated by `:`. For example: `"qwe:rty:uio".split(':') -> ["qwe", "rty", "uio"]`

`user_dict[data[0]] = data[1]` obviously saves the data into the dicionary `user_dict` taking the first string as a key, and second one as a value.

For the file mentioned above this code creates the following dictionary:

```
{"a": "52", "b": "hi", "key": "value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.strip('\n')` is removing all the \n (new line) from the string and the `split(':')` it is going to split your string using `:`
 as the delimeter into an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is storing the file into the dictionary. Content of the file is like below

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
.
.
.
key3:value3
```

Second line is stripping off the \n character from the line and then splitting the each line by : character. However you should try to understand and debug the code line by line

Answer (score 0):

`line.strip('\n')` will remove all the newlines from the string.

and

`split(':')` will split your string using ':' into array of strings.

Comment: line.strip doesn't do that ... see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Basically `line.strip('\n')` removes leading consecutive newlines and trailing consecutive newlines, but leaves embedded newlines alone. from line; and then `split(':')` separates anywhere "`:`" is.This is then stored as a list in the variable named `data`.

Comment: line.strip doesn't do that ... see my comment on previous answer

Answer (score 0):

```
data = line.strip('\n').split(':')
```

There are two string functions in one line. You also can separate the calls. This should be the same:

```
my_line = line.strip('\n')
my_line1 = my_line.split(':')
```

line.strip --> removes the new line character at the end of a line
line.split(':') --> splits the values at colon character and return a list of each record

It is easier to understand with concrete values.

Your file look like this and you loop through each line.
Name: Paul
Age: 18
Gender: Male

At the end of each line you have a "new line" character which will remove line.strip('\n').
Then you split the values at ":"
You finally create a dictionary (line 3) where key is the left side and the value is the right side.
dict['Name'] = 'Paul'
dict['Age'] = '18'

Comment: line.strip(newline) removes leading consecutive newlines and trailing consecutive newlines, but leaves embedded newlines alone. >>> "NNNtttNNNtttNNN".strip("N") produces 
'tttNNNttt'